# How to get div's ID with unique number in jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am using a jquery slider in my application.The input type hidden has got some image url paths. I want to get "

> ```
>    img-paths- <?php echo $omsg_id; ?>
> ```

"
 $omsg_id value into 
                       var image_path_id = "#img-paths-"+$(this).data('id');

when i console printed in fire bug, the output was #img-paths-undefined

how to resolve it ?

```
    <div class="post-image">
                <?php $imagePathArray = explode(',',$uploads); ?>
<input id="img-paths-<?php echo $omsg_id; ?>" type="hidden" value="<?php echo htmlentities(json_encode($imagePathArray)); ?>" />
       <div id="gallery7-<?php echo $omsg_id; ?>" ></div>
                   <script>
      $(function(e) {

            var image_path_id = "#img-paths-"+$(this).data('id');
            var show_gallery_id = "#gallery7-"+$(this).data('id');
            console.log(show_gallery_id);
            console.log(image_path_id);

            $(show_gallery_id).imagesGrid({
                images:$.parseJSON($(image_path_id).val()),
                align: true,
                getViewAllText: function(imgsCount) { return 'View all' }
            });

        });

    </script>

                  <!--<img src="<?php //echo $contentimage; ?>" class="image  show-in-modal" alt="image post">-->
                  <p><?php echo $message; ?></p>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` refers to `window` object, thus `$(this).data('id')` will not return the desired data.

You can directly use `$omsg_id` in script.

```
var image_path_id = "#img-paths-<?php echo $omsg_id; ?>";
var show_gallery_id = "#gallery7-<?php echo $omsg_id; ?>";
```